# How can I create a collection with a sequential number as one field from another collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have a variable Answers that contains a collection of AnswerDetail objects:

```
IEnumerable<AnswerDetail> Answers = ...
```

The AnswerDetail class:

```
public class AnswerDetail
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool? Response { get; set; }
}
```

The AnswerId's are unique for the application but I would like to change this so 
that they are sequential numbers starting with 1.  How can I populate the following
class, exchanging the long numbers in the source object `Answers` and putting the 
numbers 1,2,3 etc into AnswerUid field instead of the original numbers. In other words I want to completely lose the AnswerId number when sending it to the client and just send simple sequence numbers instead.

```
public class AnswerDetailToClient
{
    public int AnswerUId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool? Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a loop with a counter and change the Id for every object?

Comment: in other words.. you just want to modify the `AnswerUId`?

Comment: I was a hoping for a LINQ solution as I have seen this used before to do things in one line. Just not sure how to implement it. Also not sure if I would have to list out every field from both collections in the LINQ.

Comment: Yes I want to modify AnswerUId. I don't need to send this number to the client. I can just send a simple number like 1,2 or 3 to the client.

Comment: try to check my answer. `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Select` method overload which takes `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` delegate:

```
return Answers.Select((x,i) => { x.AnswerUID = i; return x; });
```

Change `i` with `i + 1` to get it start from `1`, otherwise it will start from `0`.

But it will modify you `Answers` collection items as well, because they are reference type instances. You could clone your objects before changing the ID to prevent that:

```
return Answers.Select(x => x.Clone())
              .Select((x,i) => { x.AnswerUID = i; return x; });
```

You have to implement `Clone` method to make it work.

Comment: This looks very good indeed. I have never even seen Clone() before !

Comment: @Alan That's because you have to implement that method to make it work :) Or you can use the library I've created lately: https://cloneextensions.codeplex.com/ It's in early development state, but because your case is rather simple should work just fine!

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Your answers really helped. Actually I decided to just do what's in your first answer. That's perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my simple solution.

```
var list = new List<AnswerDetailToClient>();
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient{AnswerUId = 100, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla"});
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient { AnswerUId = 111, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla" });
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient { AnswerUId = 222, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla" });
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient { AnswerUId = 333, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla" });
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient { AnswerUId = 444, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla" });
list.Add(new AnswerDetailToClient { AnswerUId = 555, Correct = true, Response = false, Text = "Bla bla" });

int i = 0;
var q = (from t in list
    let x = ++i
    select new
    {
        asnswerId= x,
        correct = t.Correct,
        response = t.Response,
        text = t.Text
    });
foreach (var l in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l.asnswerId);
}
Console.Read();
```